# What does this mean exactly?

Tags: combinatorics, notation

I am having trouble understanding the following notation, which I encountered studying combinatorics:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{A \subseteq \left[ n \right]} \prod_{a\in A}x_a
\end{equation}

where $[n]:=\lbrace{1,\ldots,n\rbrace}$. Can someone please give me an intuitive explanation, or, perhaps better, a combinatorial one? Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand what $$\prod_{a\in A} x_a$$ means? Now add those up for all $A\subseteq [n]$, where presumablely $[n]=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a sum of products.  For each subset of $[n]$ you multiply the corresponding $x$s.  You then add all these products.  For example, if $n=3$, we have

$$1+x_1+x_2+x_3+x_1 x_2+x_1 x_3+x_2 x_3+x_1 x_2 x_3 $$

Note the first term, $1$, corresponds to the term for the empty set, as the empty product is equal to $1$.

Comment: Interesting (at least to me) to note that this is equal to $(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdots(1+x_n)$.

Comment: Yes, it is interesting. After I fully understand the notation, it becomes clear to me why this is equal to $\sum_{A \subseteq [n]} x^{\lvert{A\rvert}}$ if we take $x_i = x,$ for every $i$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $n$ variables $x_1$ to $x_n$. Now form every product of some of these where each variable appears at most once. Add all these products together.